# Can I remove the Xcode command line tools after I install Homebrew?

Tags: xcode, homebrew

Although the Xcode command line tools (CLT) is needed during Homebrew's installation, can I uninstall the CLT after? I prefer to use gnu gcc instead of clang. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated, you can remove CLT if you want. However, in circumstances where complete removal of CLT is not specifically desirable, there are existing methods for selecting an alternate compiler such as gcc when installing a particular formula.

If you check the brew install command help (`brew install -h`) you'll see a `--cc=...` option which allows you to select a previously installed homebrew compiler. For example `brew install r --cc=gcc-7`.

Again, if the only compiler you want on your PATH is gcc, removal of CLT may be a viable option. However, for the sake of clarity, within the Homebrew framework there are other options that may be more suitable depending on the circumstances.

Comment: I see -- not only we'd need the LLVM/Clang compiler in the CLT to install Homebrew, we need it to install additional Homebrew packages too (without specifying the `--cc=` option).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, launch xcode then go to:

Preference -> locations

And remove the selected line in command line tools

Comment: Does Homebrew need the CLT to function (e.g., when installing a package)?  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure, you can try it by taking out the CLT and then trying to install somethimg with brew